# Change view and remove element by Ext.Component.query

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-modern

I have a TabPanel like this:

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {

Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
items: [
    {
        title: "",
        reference: 'tabpanel',
        itemId: 'tab1',
        items: [{
            itemId: 'firstTab',
            xclass: 'viewClass'
        }],
    }, {
        title: "",
        reference: 'tab2',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            xclass: "view",
        }]
    }
]
```

in the xclass component there is the path of a class where is defined the view. In the view should be a button, after tap on it, the view should refresh and show another class, for example the view should be defined by 'viewClass2' and not anymore by 'viewClass' I'm imaging a function triggered on button tap like this:

```
        Ext.getCmp('tab1').remove('firstTab');
        Ext.getCmp('tab1').add({
            itemId: 'firstTab',
            xclass: 'viewClass2'
        })
```

BUT I must use `itemId` and not `id` so I cannot use "`Ext.getCmp`" and i should use `Ext.Component.query` but I don't know how to manage remove and add operations

Answer (score 0):

You have to get reference of the component first, then remove it.

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
id: 'myTabPanel',
items: [
    {
        title: "",
        reference: 'tabpanel',
        itemId: 'tab1',
        items: [{
            itemId: 'firstTab',
            xclass: 'viewClass'
        }],
    }, {
        title: "",
        reference: 'tab2',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            xclass: "view",
        }]
    }
];

var tabPanel = Ext.getCmp('myTabPanel');
var tab = tabPanel.getComponent("tab1");

// remove by id
tab.remove(tab.down("[itemId='firstTab']").id);
// remove by reference
tab.remove(tab.down("[itemId='firstTab']"));
```

Comment: I cannot get an itemId using Ext.getCmp so Ext.getCmp('tab1') doesn't work

Comment: sry i saw it wrong. Can you give an id to tabpanel itself? then you can get it by getCmp and use “down” method as i did to reference it. İf you cant, set it to a variable where you call Ext.create and then you can use it the same way.